# Wrong output in c++ , i=65530 and when we print value of i it gives -6 instate of 65530. why?

Tags: c++

I was creating a simple variable printing program and there is unexpected output.
The program gives output -6, but I would have expected 65530.

Why?

```cpp
#include<iostream>

int main(){
    short int i=65530;
    std::cout<<i;
}
```

Comment: You want `unsigned short` instead of `short int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with the binary represenation of the type you have used.

As a 16 bit binary: `65530` === `1111 1111 1111 1010`

But you have used `short int` which is a **signed** number and in it's binary definition it is represented by 1 bit as a sign and 15 bits as the number:

`(1)111 1111 1111 1010`

- So why are there so many 1's in the representation?
- Why don't the 15 bits look like a `6` in binary ( `(1)000 0000 0000 0110`)?

It's because of the way that negative numbers are represented in binary.

To represent signed numbers in binary, a format is used which is called [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

So here is an example of this transformation of the number `-6`

1. Take the number and transform it to binary. (`6` in binary === `0000 0000 0000 0110`
2. Exchange `1`'s to `0`'s and `0`'s to `1`'s (`1111 1111 1111 1001`)
3. To get the result - Add `1` to the previous transformation: (`1111 1111 1111 1010`)

As You can see exactly the same binary representation is for (unsigned)`65530` as is for (signed)`-6`.

It's all in the interpretation of the bits.
That's why You have to be carefull nearing the maximum values of a representation in a type.

In this case to store this value You could:

1. Change the type to `unsigned short int`
2. Change to larger type.

Answer (score 1):

You declared i as a short int, which is a 16-bit signed type. This means that the highest number it can represent is actually 32767 (2^15-1) and the smallest is -32768 (-2^15). 65530 overflows that limit. So if you had printed 32768, it would instead overflow to -32768, 32769 would overflow to -32767 and so on. See more topics on binary representations of signed numbers to understand this process better